# bootstrap row class abolished proper side padding in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://bootply.com/101886

why the second row left a gab there? I want to ask is this the right way or the right markup of a template? I found sometime my div isn't aligned properly. Do you guys think use container again to wrap all the `<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">` is a good practice? because when you resize into mobile, there isn't padding.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do?
http://bootply.com/101968

I think paddings for the background is not necessary but for texts it is better to have proper paddings in mobile view, which is Bootstrap3's default settings.